# jquery css3 question

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a way to write this more elegantly??

```
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(1)").css("background-color", "#FBE9E7");
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(1)").css("padding", "4px");
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(2)").css("background-color", "#FBE9E7");
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(2)").css("padding", "4px");
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(3)").css("background-color", "#FBE9E7");
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(3)").css("padding", "4px");
```

Comment: Is this to be done for each of the elements in the list, or always just the first three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go:

```
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(1)").addClass('someClass')
```

That way you can get all of the CSS out of your JS.

Comment: $("li.list_restaurant_item:lt(3)").addClass('listPageHighlights');

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you can avoid the redundant lookups:

```
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(1), li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(2), li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(3)").css({
    "background-color": "#FBE9E7",
    "padding", "4px"
});
```

Or depending on your markup, the [`:lt` selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) might do it:

```
$("li.list_restaurant_item:lt(3)").css({
    "background-color": "#FBE9E7",
    "padding", "4px"
});
```

Note that unlike `:nth-child`, `:lt` indexes are `0`-based, and so the above matches the first three items (`0`, `1`, and `2`).

Answer (score 1):

you can write:

```
$("li.list_restaurant_item").slice(0, 3).css({"background-color": "#FBE9E7", "padding": "4px");
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire scope of the task at hand it note specifically clear, but you could make this clearer by creating a style and adding / removing that as necessary.

Create a re-usable style:

```
.MyStyleClass { background-color:#FBE9E7; padding:4px; }
```

Add the class as required, per item:

```
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(1)").addClass("MyStyleClass");
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(2)").addClass("MyStyleClass");
$("li.list_restaurant_item:nth-child(3)").addClass("MyStyleClass");
```

If this is to be done for all items in the list, then you could possibly use the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method on the list element. Something like this might do the trick:

```
$.each($("li.list_restaurant_item").children(), function () {
    $(this).addClass("MyStyleClass");
});
```